# I18n documentation framework

Tags: git, frameworks, internationalization

I want to move my documentation to Markdown to improve the editing process. As part of this move, a system for internationalizing the documentation is needed.

I would like it to meet the following criteria:

- Markdown documents will be stored in Git and updated frequently, so the proposal should address automated translation template generation.
- Translators should be able to quickly determine what parts of a document have changed and modify their existing translation only where necessary.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: This is really way too broad. There is simply no way of answering this in the current form.

Comment: @PawełDyda So how should I ask, to get what I want ? I don't want you to rewrite it, just point me in the right direction.

Comment: That's tough question. I have no choice, but to show you [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I especially like [Jon's "Writing perfect question"](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (he knows what he's talking about, he is the top guy here).

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint you, I just don't think there is one concise answer to your question and any answer would have to be opinion based (which is not welcomed on this forum). On the other hand, I am scratching my head and asking myself why in the world you want to keep documentation in the software repository? Personally, I think that some kind of CMS would be much more suitable for this task (especially if bundled with right collection of plugins).

Comment: @PawełDyda thanks :) And where can I ask this question ? I don't mind the answer to be opinion-based.